# Break multi line function call

Tags: go

I am working on a library / wrapper for mysql in go. For usage of my API I imagined something like:

```
model
    .Select("INTERNAL_ID")
    .Select("EXTERNAL_ID")
    .Find(1);
```

With, as example, the following functions:

```
func (model SQLModel) Select(selectString string) SQLModel 
func (model SQLModel) Find(id int) interface{}
```

The problem is that I can't break my function calls into multiple lines as go/fmt complains: `syntax error: unexpected ., expecting }` at every break.

Now, I could go :

```
model.Select("INTERNAL_ID").Select("EXTERNAL_ID").Find(1)
```

But as the API grows (where, join, sum, etc, ...) it'll rapidly become hard to read.

So, how can I split function calls in GO ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The dots must be at the end of line:

```
model.
    Select("INTERNAL_ID").
    Select("EXTERNAL_ID").
    Find(1)
```

Comment: Indeed... Thanks. I'll mark accepted in 10 min

Comment: For Detailed answer Refer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34846848/how-to-break-a-long-line-of-code-in-golang