# Multiple return values in multiple lines

Tags: go, return, return-type

How to return multiple Values in multiple lines in GoLang?

```
  if  x == y {
    req, _ := cgi.Request()
    return req.FormValue("a"),
      req.FormValue("b"),
      req.FormValue("c"),
      req.FormValue("d"),
      req.FormValue("e"),

  } else {
      ...
  }
```

> ./example.go:9:3: syntax error: unexpected }, expecting expression

Comment: Your `if` statement `x = y` is invalid, you likely intended `x == y`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a composite literal or function call, you must not put a trailing comma after the last line:

```
return req.FormValue("a"),
  req.FormValue("b"),
  req.FormValue("c"),
  req.FormValue("d"),
  req.FormValue("e")
```

See an example:

```
func f() (int, int, string) {
    return 1,
        2,
        "3"
}
```

Testing it:

```
fmt.Println(f())
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/KedmpjlubfQ)):

```
1 2 3
```

See related question: [How to break a long line of code in Golang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34846848/how-to-break-a-long-line-of-code-in-golang/34848928#34848928)