# Syntax rule for opening brace in Go for-loop

Tags: for-loop, go, syntax, curly-braces

#### Case 1

This program compiles successfully:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    i := 0
    for ; i < 3; i++ {
        fmt.Println(i)
    }
}
```

#### Case 2

But this does not:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    i := 0
    for ; i < 3; i++
    {
        fmt.Println(i)
    }
}
```

This leads to error:

```
./prog.go:9:18: syntax error: unexpected newline, expecting { after for clause
```

#### Case 3

But this compiles successfully:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    i := 0
    for
    {
        fmt.Println(i)
    }
}
```

#### Question

Why is it that in case 2, the opening brace for `for` is not allowed in the next line but in case 3 it is allowed?

Comment: The last should probably not be allowed, it might be a bug, but it's not 100% clear from my reading of the spec based on https://golang.org/ref/spec#For_statements and https://golang.org/ref/spec#Blocks

Comment: Why the downvotes? How could I have made this question better?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In short, when you have this in line:

```
for ; i < 3; i++
```

a semicolon will be inserted automatically, resulting in syntax error.

[Spec: Semicolons:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Semicolons)

> When the input is broken into tokens, a semicolon is automatically inserted into the token stream immediately after a line's final token if that token is
>
> - an [identifier](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Identifiers)
> - an [integer](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Integer_literals), [floating-point](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Floating-point_literals), [imaginary](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Imaginary_literals), [rune](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Rune_literals), or [string](https://golang.org/ref/spec#String_literals) literal
> - one of the [keywords](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Keywords) `break`, `continue`, `fallthrough`, or `return`
> - **one of the [operators and punctuation](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Operators_and_punctuation) `++`, `--`, `)`, `]`, or `}`**

So in **Case 2** the lexer will automatically insert a semicolon at the end of the line which when present will "render" the code syntactically incorrect.

Not in **Case 3** when there is only a `for` in a line, no semicolon is inserted (as per the quoted rules above, semicolon is only inserted after the `break`, `continue`, `fallthrough` and `return` keywords). So in **Case 3** the code will not be extended with a semicolon and will remain syntactically correct.

For more details, see [How to break a long line of code in Golang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34846848/how-to-break-a-long-line-of-code-in-golang/34848928#34848928)

Answer (score -3):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    i := 0
    for ; i < 3; i++{
        fmt.Println(i)
    }
}
```

works its just that putting `{` in a new line causes the error you get.

in case 3 you don't have any statement to evaluate, so new line doesn't cause an y problem.