# Query MongoDB Aggregation framework with Golang

Tags: sql, mongodb, go, frameworks, aggregate

I have in a collection stores , products and many prices (for store-products there are many prices) of the products in MongoDB
I have to find out min price from a product in a store in the last 30 days with the help of go
I have built the following aggregation pipeline

```
pipeline := []bson.M{
        bson.D{
            "$group", bson.D{
                {
                    "_id", bson.D{
                        {
                            Key:   "storeId",
                            Value: "$storeUd",
                        },
                        {
                            Key:   "productId",
                            Value: "$productId",
                        },
                    },
                },
                minPrice : {
                    Key:   "min",
                    Value: "$price",
                },
            },
        }  <---
}
```

But go compiler tell me in the line that I marked with an arrow (<---)  there is a mistake

syntax error: unexpected newline in composite literal; possibly missing comma or }

I would like to calculate something like

```
select min(price)
from prices
group by storeId , productId
```

Please can you tell me what is wrong?

Thanks,
Aurel

---

I added }, but what I get you can see in the attached picture - the next declaration (var ... ) is in red ....
[image]

Comment: You have to add a final comma! `},` See possible duplicate: [How to break a long line of code in Golang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34846848/how-to-break-a-long-line-of-code-in-golang/34848928#34848928)